# File Server vs NAS for hosting media files

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, system-administration, infrastructure, nas

I have a web portal where my users can login and submit artworks (image, documents, etc.). This web portal is hosted in 2 load-balanced web servers.

Because of this load balancing, I'm thinking of using NAS to serve as a centralized media file storage for my web portal. I'm considering NAS because it's cheaper than a file server and it's easier to maintain.

Now the questions are:

1. File hosting - Is there any NAS device that can act as a file hosting server? Or, do I need to create a virtual path in my web server to the NAS? This can be achieved easily if I use a file server, I can just bind a separate domain to the file server, something like media.mydomain.com, so all media files will be served through this domain. I don't mind serving the media files through a virtual path from my web servers, smthg like mydomain.com/media. I would like to know if NAS can do any of the approaches above, and whether it's secure, easy to setup, etc.
2. Performance - This is more important because read and writes are quite intensive. I never use NAS before. I'm thinking of getting 2 hard drives (2TB, 15000RPM) configured for RAID-1. Would this be able to match the performance of a common file server? I know the answer to this question is relative but I just want to see how NAS can be used as a file hosting, not just as a file sharing device.

My web servers are running Windows Server 2008R2 with IIS 7.5. I would appreciate if anyone can also share best practices for integrating NAS with Win Server/IIS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. A NAS provides a shared location for information on a private network (at least you shouldn't expose NAS technologies as NFS and CIFS over the internet) and is not really designed as a web file host. That is not to say you can't configure a NAS as a web file host utilizing IIS/apache/nginx, but then you don't need your web servers.  NAS setup is well documented for both windows server and most unix/linux distros, both are relatively easy.  A NAS is as secure as it is designed to be, you can utilize a variety of access control methods to secure a NAS depending on your implementation.
2. This really depends on your concurrent users and what kind of load you are expecting them to put on the system, for the most part performance over a 1Gb LAN connection and a 15,000 RPM hard drive for a NAS should provide ample performance for a decent amount of concurrent users, but I can't say for certain because if a user sits there downloading hundreds of files at a time you can have issues.  As with any web technology wrap limits around user usage to prevent one user bringing down your entire system. I'm not sure what you are defining a file server (a NAS is a file server), if you think of a file server as a website that hosts files, a NAS will provide the same if not better performance based on where the device is in relation to your web servers (again, depending on utilization).  If you are worried about performance you can always build a larger RAID array using RAID 5, RAID 6, RAID 10 or use SSDs to increase storage performance.  For the most part in any NAS the hardware constraints usually are: storage speed, network speed, ram, cpu.  **Again this really depends on utilization, so test well, benchmark, and monitor performance**

Microsoft provides a tuning document for server 2008 r2 that is useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463392.aspx

In my opinion your architecture would be your 2 web servers referencing the NAS as a shared location using a virtual directory pointed at the NAS for your files or handle the NAS location in code (using code provides a whole plethora of options around security and usage).